# Advances in Intelligent Systems and Computing (AISC) template for Latex?

Tags: formatting, latex

While I am looking for Latex template of the AISC template (Advances in Intelligent Systems and Computing), I could find only its word format in following link:

https://www.springer.com/gp/authors-editors/journal-author/word-template-zip-154-kb-/22044

Does it mean that there is no Latex template for AISC?

Meanwhile, after downloading the word template, it seems to be similar to LNCS (Lecture Notes in Computer Science). Could be they the same?

Comment: Ask the publishers/editors of AISC.

Comment: @Wolfgang Bangerth , I may need to contact Springer, since the file does not exist for downloading in its site (ftp://ftp.springernature.com/cs-proceeding/svproc/templates/ProcSci_TeX.zip)

Answer (score 1):

*This kind of questions are not encouraged in this site.* However, here is what I found.

There is LaTeX template for this here: https://www.springer.com/gp/authors-editors/conference-proceedings/conference-proceedings-guidelines

Comment: Thank you. Yes, in fact I had tried this page before, but the file does not exist: (LINK: ftp://ftp.springernature.com/cs-proceeding/svproc/templates/ProcSci_TeX.zip)

Comment: It's working for me.

Comment: I however receive this message: screenshot: https://ibb.co/qsByVTy